# Read in all csv files from a directory using Python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, numpy, genfromtxt

I hope this is not trivial but I am wondering the following:

If I have a specific folder with *n* `csv` files, how could I iteratively read all of them, one at a time, and perform some calculations on their values?

For a single file, for example, I do something like this and perform some calculations on the `x` array:

```
import csv
import os

directoryPath=raw_input('Directory path for native csv file: ') 
csvfile = numpy.genfromtxt(directoryPath, delimiter=",")
x=csvfile[:,2] #Creates the array that will undergo a set of calculations
```

I know that I can check how many `csv` files there are in a given folder (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234560/find-all-csv-files-in-a-directory-using-python)):

```
import glob
for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print files
```

But I failed to figure out how to possibly nest the `numpy.genfromtxt()` function in a for loop, so that I read in all the csv files of a directory that it is up to me to specify.

**EDIT**

The folder I have only has `jpg` and `csv` files. The latter are named `eventX.csv`, where *X* ranges from 1 to 50. The `for` loop I am referring to should therefore consider the file names the way they are.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's how I'd do it:

```
import os

directory = os.path.join("c:\\","path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
           #  perform calculation
           f.close()
```

Comment: Can the `f.close()` line be placed right after I define `x=csvfile[:,2]`? The number `2` is just exemplificative.

Comment: And, if I may add, is your code checking for all `csv` files in ALL folders within `directory`?

Comment: as a note, the recommended way of opening files is `with open(file) as file` this has the advantage of closing automatically when out of scope

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani for your first question: you can do this but you won't be able do do any other operation on the file. As for the second, it only lists all files in a directory. If you want all files from all folders within a direcory you can store each folder from directory in a list and then get the .csv from each folder at a time.

Comment: Could you please explain this line, os.path.join("c:\\","path")

Answer (score 18):

Using pandas and glob as the base packages

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

glued_data = pd.DataFrame()
for file_name in glob.glob(directoryPath+'*.csv'):
    x = pd.read_csv(file_name, low_memory=False)
    glued_data = pd.concat([glued_data,x],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you look for something like this

```
import glob

for file_name in glob.glob(directoryPath+'*.csv'):
    x = np.genfromtxt(file_name,delimiter=',')[:,2]
    # do your calculations
```

**Edit**

If you want to get all `csv` files from a folder (including subfolder) you could use `subprocess` instead of `glob` (note that this code only works on linux systems)

```
import subprocess
file_list = subprocess.check_output(['find',directoryPath,'-name','*.csv']).split('\n')[:-1]

for i,file_name in enumerate(file_list):
    x = np.genfromtxt(file_name,delimiter=',')[:,2]
    # do your calculations
    # now you can use i as an index
```

It first searches the folder and sub-folders for all file_names using the `find` command from the shell and applies your calculations afterwards.

Comment: Well I very like this handy and short solution but I tested it and it did not yield what I wanted. I created a new empty folder, placed three `csv` files in it named `file_1.csv`, `file_2.csv`, and `file_3.csv`, each of which has the value `1`, `2`, and `3` as unique value (without header). Then I created `a=numpy.zeros(3)` to fill it with those values but I get `a=([0,0,0])`. In the `for` loop, the new values of `a` are assigned like this: `a[file_name]=numpy.genfromtxt(file_name,delimiter=',')[0,0]`. Instead of `a=([1,2,3])` I get `a=([0,0,0])`.

Comment: Hmm ... it worked for my simple examples ... let me check what could go wrong ...

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani : `file_name` is a string in my code ... what do you mean with `a[file_name]`? `a[...]` requires an integer ... aren't there any errors?

Comment: No, no errors. I was attempting to use `file_name` as a counter variable  since it carries the exact number of files (and of values) of this test case. I made this up just to test your hint. If we can't use `file_name` as counter, what could we use? Should we add a nested loop to add a counter ranging 1 to 3?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani : what happens when you use `print x` instead of `a[file_name]=...` ? Do you obtain `1 2 3` ?

Comment: It does not print anything. I've probably got it: as you say, I was attempting to use `file_name` as a counter variable since it carries the exact number of files (and of values) of this test case. I made this up just to test your hint. If we can't use `file_name` as integer, what could we use? Should we add a nested loop to add a counter ranging 1 to 3?

Comment: Then I assume that `file_list` is empty. `np.genfromtxt` raises an error when a file does not exist and if it reads the file there should be some output. Thus, the problem is related to the `find` command. Do you use the full path for the directory path?

Comment: Yes. In my case that is `C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\prova`.

Comment: Oh, then the problem is that you use Windows because (as far as I know) the command `find` does not exist (or does not work) as I used it in my program. ... Hmm, let me see whether I can rewrite that part in order to work for you

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani : [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1724723/4367286) you can find an algorithm which hopefully helps you build the `file_list`. Unfortunately I can not help you more because I am not working on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) of `numpy.genfromtxt()`, the first argument can be a

> File, filename, or generator to read.

That would mean that you could write a generator that yields the lines of all the files like this:

```
def csv_merge_generator(pattern):
    for file in glob.glob(pattern):
        for line in file:
            yield line

# then using it like this

numpy.genfromtxt(csv_merge_generator('*.csv'))
```

should work. (I do not have numpy installed, so cannot test easily)

Comment: Would your last line be nested in a `for` loop?

Comment: nonono, it is passed in the generator, and as such gets all the files

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more succinct way to do this, given some `path = "/path/to/dir/"`.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(path+'*.csv')])
```

Then you can apply your calculation to the whole dataset, or, if you want to apply it one by one:

```
pd.concat([process(pd.read_csv(f)) for f in glob.glob(path+'*.csv')])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pathlib` `glob` functionality to list all .csv in a path, and `pandas` to read them.
Then it's only a matter of applying whatever function you want (which, if systematic, can also be done within the list comprehension)

```
import pands as pd
from pathlib import Path

path2csv = Path("/your/path/")
csvlist = path2csv.glob("*.csv")
csvs = [pd.read_csv(g) for g in csvlist ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another answer using list comprehension:

```
from os import listdir
files= [f for f in listdir("./") if f.endswith(".csv")]
```

Comment: I like this one with no extra dependency!

Answer (score 1):

The function below will return a dictionary containing a *dataframe* for each .csv file in the folder within your **defined path**.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import ntpath

def panda_read_csv(path):
    pd_csv_dict = {}
    csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
    for csv_file in csv_files:
        file_name = ntpath.basename(csv_file)
        pd_csv_dict['pd_' + file_name] = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=";", encoding='mac_roman')
    locals().update(pd_csv_dict)
    return pd_csv_dict
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the glob library and then use it like following:

```
import  glob
path='C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\db_conection_screenshot\\seclectors_absent_images'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.png")
print(len(filenames))
```

Comment: This merely seems to repeat information from several previous answers without adding any explanation or new value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).