# Not able to read csv files in sequence

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu-16.04

I wanted to build a list of all the csv files in a folder and read them to a dataframe.  So I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503993/read-in-all-csv-files-from-a-directory-using-python) and and was able to get all the csv files in a desired folder. Then when I attempt to read in each folder iteratively, I get an error that the specific folder doesn't exist.

```
import os

directory = os.path.join("/home/5G-production-dataset/5G-production-dataset/Download","Driving/")

print(directory) ## works

df_final = pd.DataFrame() ## each dataframe read will be concatenated to this

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    print(f"files = {files}") ## gives a list with all the filenames as elements
    for file in files:
        print(f"current file is {file} and the type is {type(file)}") ## prints the current file and dtype is string
        if file.endswith(".csv"):

           df = pd.read_csv(file) ## error that the files doess't exist
           print(len(df))
           df_final = pd.concat([df], axis = 0, ignore_index=True)


print(len(df_final))
```

*I verified the filenames and it is from the list contains all the files that I want to read. The full error is*

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-65d96982fe32> in <module>
     13         #    f=open(file, 'r')
     14            #  perform calculation
---> 15            df = pd.read_csv(file)
     16            print(len(df))
     17            df_final = pd.concat([df], axis = 0, ignore_index=True)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'B_2019.12.16_14.23.32.csv' does not exist: b'B_2019.12.16_14.23.32.csv'
```

Could this be causing as a result of the filenames having multiple dot (.) symbols ? I have a lot of files and can't check them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you need to specify the file path relative to the script itself:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, file))
```