# How to take the csv files from an automatically creating folders using python

Tags: python, pandas

a folder is creating automatically  by running a function and in that folders csv files are creating. How to take the csv files from that folders using python

Comment: The following should give you that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503993/read-in-all-csv-files-from-a-directory-using-python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: but it is reading from one folder only. Here in my code the folders are creating automatically and i need to read the csv files from the generated new folders every time