# How do can I assign a list of variables to a certain list of csv file?

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried to manually assign each and every files to a certain variable, but that is not something that I am aiming for the time being. I want to assign the these files to a certain variable so that it can be reproduceable and easy to use? Would anyone suggest me to do that?

My files are as follows

```
path = 'filepath*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
   print(fname)
```

Comment: Please, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234560/find-all-csv-files-in-a-directory-using-python/12280052

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to accomplish? Your end goal is most likely something else than just assigning variables.

Comment: yes my final aim is definitely different from what i have mentioned here