# How to delete .DS_Store file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I'm using python to read CSV files inside a folder and after to perform calculations.

Some times inside the folder there are ".DS_Store files". When the algorithm reads one of those files everything blows up.

Those files are easy to delete manually.

How can I achieve a built-in function inside my code? (here is the part of the code that reads the files)

```py
for i in range(10):
    M1 = genfromtxt(listOfFiles[i], delimiter=',', encoding='unicode_escape')
```

Comment: Can we see how you generate the `listOfFiles`? It's likely possible to exclude `.DS_Store` from the array

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to delete the `.DS_Store` file.

You can select only the `.CSV` to read. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234560/find-all-csv-files-in-a-directory-using-python) discusses some ways to do so.